# What is the use of prevstate?

Tags: reactjs

When we dont use prevstate, the code is like this:

```
state = {
   count: 0
}
updateCount = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1}); \\count = 0 + 1 = 1
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
}
```

so in this for ever setState current value of count is used. So in first setState this.state.count = 0 + 1 = 1. then in second setState, the value of this.state.count would be 1 hence it would be increased by 1 that is this.state.count = 1 + 1 = 2;

But it is not like that. why?
Then why we required prestate like this:

```
updateCount = () => {
    this.setState(prevstate => ({ count: prevstate.count + 1}));
    this.setState(prevstate => ({ count: prevstate.count + 1}));
    this.setState(prevstate => ({ count: prevstate.count + 1}));
    this.setState(prevstate => ({ count: prevstate.count + 1}));
}
```

Comment: Because [setState may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: @AjeetShah so using callback in setState is it become synchronously

Comment: No. But it makes sure that all pending / batched `setState` calls were executed before executing the current one. And, that's how `prevState` gives you the **latest** state.